# Adding multiple columns to dataframe and skip empty values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
s = {'B1': ['1C', '3A', '41A'], 'B2':['','1A','28A'], 'B3':['','','3A'],
     'B1_m':['2','2','2'], 'B2_m':['2','4','2'],'B3_m':['2','2','4'], 
     'E':['0','0','0']}
s = DataFrame(s)
print(s)

    B1   B2  B3 B1_m B2_m B3_m  E
0   1C             2    2    2  0
1   3A   1A        2    4    2  0
2  41A  28A  3A    2    2    4  0
```

and I add these multiple columns to a new colum `Results` by this format:

```
s['Results'] = s['B1']+s['B1_m']+'-'+s['B2']+s['B2_m']+'-'+s['B3']+s['B3_m']+'-'+s['E']
print(s)

    B1   B2  B3  B1_m  B2_m  B3_m   E            Results
0   1C              2     2     2   0          1C2-2-2-0
1   3A   1A         2     4     2   0        3A2-1A4-2-0
2  41A  28A  3A     2     2     4   0    41A2-28A2-3A4-0
```

But, what I want is skip the item if there's empty value in B1-B3, like this:

```
    B1   B2  B3  B1_m  B2_m  B3_m   E            Results
0   1C              2     2     2   0              1C2-0
1   3A   1A         2     4     2   0          3A2-1A4-0
2  41A  28A  3A     2     2     4   0    41A2-28A2-3A4-0
```

Is there any ways for conditionally skip those empty value?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the most pythonic way I can think to solve this:

```
import numpy as np

s['Results'] = s['B1']+s['B1_m'] + \
                  np.where(s['B2'], '-'+s['B2']+s['B2_m'], "") + \
                  np.where(s['B3'], '-'+s['B3']+s['B3_m'], "") +'-'+s['E']
```

Will obtain the results you want:

```
print(s)
    B1   B2  B3 B1_m B2_m B3_m  E          Results
0   1C             2    2    2  0            1C2-0
1   3A   1A        2    4    2  0        3A2-1A4-0
2  41A  28A  3A    2    2    4  0  41A2-28A2-3A4-0
```

(Note that the `\` are required to insert a line break during the long statement).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) single digits using regex and concat column `E` as:

```
s['Results'] = s['Results'].str.replace(r'\b\-[0-9]\b','')+'-'+s['E']
```

Or:

```
s['Results'] = s['Results'].str.replace(r'\b\-\d\b','')+'-'+s['E']
```

---

```
print(s)
    B1   B2  B3 B1_m B2_m B3_m  E          Results
0   1C             2    2    2  0            1C2-0
1   3A   1A        2    4    2  0        3A2-1A4-0
2  41A  28A  3A    2    2    4  0  41A2-28A2-3A4-0
```

If the digits are more than one then use:

```
s['Results'] = s['Results'].str.replace(r'\b\-\d+\b','')+'-'+s['E']
```